systemd service for openvpn vs networkmanager-openvpn
I am using Yocto for a rpi4 target. I was using a systemd service to activate my VPN over openvpn at boot:
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN connection to .ovpn file
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-%i --status /run/openvpn-client/%i.status 10 -cd /etc/openvpn/client/ --config /etc/openvpn/client/%i.ovpn
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPIDy
WorkingDirectory=/etc/openvpn/client

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
 

I was using, Networkmanager + Openvpn package in yocto. Lately, I discovered the package Networkmanager-openvpn. What is the purpose of this package ? How to use it ?

NetworkManager supports external network types via a plugin API. It's often called "NetworkManager's VPN plugins" and the VPN plugin API.
In that case, you install the plugin and create NetworkManager connection profiles of type connection.type=vpn.
There are various VPN plugins, like openvpn, openconnect, libreswan, strongswan, etc.
In that case, you no longer run the openvpn executable directly. NetworkManager and the plugin will do it when you activate the profile.
The benefit is that those plugins integrate with NetworkManager. For example,

DNS resolution can be configured in a unified way, and you don't have multiple services (NetworkManager and openvpn) fight over writing /etc/resolv.conf (which doesn't work, as alternative to that problem, the services could use resolvconf tool or systemd-resolved).
you use the common tools for the VPN, that you also use with NetworkManager already (nmcli, GUI).
you don't need to be root, permissions are controlled via policykit.
the whole point of NetworkManager is to provide an API for controlling the network. Consequently, there are tools (e.g. GUI) that builds on that.

The plugins usually also provide a GTK part, which integrates with gnome-shell, gnome-control-center, nm-applet, nm-connection-editor. KDE's plasma-nm doesn't use the GTK part, but implement their own. So there is GUI support and they integrate in the way how networking is configured on your desktop environment.
One downside for NetworkManager-openvpn is that it doesn't drop as many privileges as it should. That's a bug/missing feature. If you run openvpn binary directly, you would be able to sandbox it better.

To use NetworkManger-openvpn plugin, install it (that may need a restart of NetworkManager service). Afterwards, as always. Create a connection profile in NetworkManager and activate it with nmcli connection up "$PROFILE". See the contents with nmcli connection show "$PROFILE".
You can use nmcli connection import --type openvpn --file my-vpn.ovpn to create a connection profile.
Or use nm-connection-editor to import/edit the profile (if you also install the GTK part, which may be in a separate package). Maybe you don't have a GUI on your yocto, but you can do this on your workstation, use the GUI to configure a profile, and then copy over the file from /etc/NetworkManager/system-connection. Or at least, use the GUI to see which options are there and how they are realized in nmcli or in file. Otherwise, it can be a bit hard to figure out all the options, as the documentation is lacking.

Very helpul. Tnx!
